# Application of SCR & TRIAC in electronics Field

Tags: power, basic, power-electronics

What are the main applications of an SCR in analog electronics as well as in digital electronics? I only heard them in my books I have seen only usage of transistors, MOSFETs, FET's during the designing of a circuit. Why not SCR or TRIAC or others? What are the basic parameters to select these components during the designing of a circuits.

Comment: Could you rephrase this so that it makes sense?

Comment: I'm guessing by "electronics field" you mean analog electronics, and by "software field", you mean digital electronics.

Answer (score 2):

SCRs and TRIACs are used with alternating current. The problem with their use for DC is that once they turn on, they don't turn off until you remove the power.

With AC the power is removed twice every cycle (on every zero crossing) so those devices are used.

Comment: @ Pentium 100 As far as i know electronics circuits works only on DC source so they dont have any application in electroncis field?

Comment: Electronics work with DC and AC. Lamp dimmers use TRIACs for example. Also, in some cases TRIACs and SCRs (instead of relays) are used to control motors. SCRs are also used in HVDC transmission (as rectifiers).

Comment: @SHASWAT The majority of electronics applications is indeed in DC, but there is electronics for AC aswell. AC applications are generally power electronics, so indeed dimming a light bulb, but many commuter trains run from high voltage AC (like up to 25kV in Europe). Some washing machines use thyristors (=SRC) (or maybe TRIACs), to control power to the motor. Also preregulators for heavy duty power supplies use SCR/TRIAC pre-regulation.